# Why is my page resulting in a redirect loop?

Tags: php, regex

I have a series of commands that check whether a url looks something like

```
http://localhost/questions/32/new-question-from-peter
```

and if the last part is missing I redirect to this. I do allow for a fragment at the end.
However, i would like to add a possibilty for it to be

```
http://localhost/questions/32/new-question-from-peter?page= <int>
```

Here is my code

```
if($question){
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $dashed = $question->dashed_title;
    $pattern = '/^\/questions\/[0-9]+\/'.$dashed.'(\/#[0-9]+)?$/i';

    if (!preg_match($pattern, $url)){
    // redirect_301 is a function that I wrote
        redirect_301('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/questions/'.$question->id.'/'.$dashed);
    }
}
```

At the moment it works fine and will always redirect to the correct path. But it will not let me append

```
?page=<int>.
```

So i thought that the pattern should be

```
$pattern = '/^\/questions\/[0-9]+\/'.$dashed.'((\/#[0-9]+)|(?[\w\d&=]+))?$/i';
```

But this is resulting in a redirect loop and I cant work out why. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the ending `$` from your original pattern, since that is the end of the string, so it won't match if there is a query string.

Comment: Thanks for that, but that would allow any normal letters after the title, how can i arrange that only a ? is allowed

Comment: Replace the `$` in the original regexp with `(\?.*)?$` (note the escaped "?".

Comment: BTW, the hash component of the URL is *never* visible to the web server... it is a client-side only component.

Comment: do you mean the request_uri doesnt include the hash component?